# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to figure out what is creating this error

My code is simple:

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">nsnsn</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function rSizer(){
    var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
    alert(bg.innerHTML); //error occurs on this line
}
document.ready(rSizer());
window.on('resize', rSizer());
```

Comment: I don't believe there's such a thing as `document.ready`... there is `$(document).ready()`, but not `document.ready`

Comment: @myfunkyside It's javascript. Total software Vietnam. You don't know whether there's a `document.ready` in Nick's context ;)

Comment: (but I'm sure you're right)

Comment: @myfunkyside The document.ready change didn't affect my JS error at all. the error still persists on the same line

Comment: I bet it changed the stack trace. You need to change the `window.on` line as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ad119d6h/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="bg">nsnsn</div>
```

**JS**

```
function rSizer(){
    var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
    console.log(bg.innerHTML); //error occurs on this line
}
$(document).ready(rSizer);
$(window).on('resize',rSizer);
```

Works fine for me (told ya to change that `document` and `window` ;)

also, what Chris said..

---

### UPDATE (pure JS no jquery)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ad119d6h/5/

```
window.onload = rSizer;
window.onresize = rSizer;
```

(the rest is the same)

Comment: Can I get this in pure JS (no jquery)?

Answer (score 5):

I think instead of `document.ready(rSizer());` you meant `document.ready(rSizer);`.

Comment: This is not a problem. The function is called and google chrome's console says there is an error on that line, so the function did execute partially.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. It executed too soon. Because you're calling it directly from your script rather than letting it be called by jquery after the DOM is ready.